# Inconsistency with a toString method?

Tags: javascript

```
var o = {
  valueOf: function () {
    return 1;
  },
  toString: function () {
    return 'haha, intercepted';
  }
};
```

If I go ahead and log `a` object, that would mean `o.toString()`, (getting me the stringy representation of the object) meaning, it will find the method earlier (in its own object) and will log the `haha, intercepted`.

```
console.log(o); // Object { toString: toString() }
```

but it logs the object it self. Managed to find the proper method anyway. What that inconsistency?

Also, if I go and perform addition operation it works as it should with `valueOf` method applied to the object `o`. Tries to find the primitive value of that object so it can add 1 to it, but this one I managed to trick it by setting it manually.

```
console.log(o + 1); // 2
```

Comment: The behavior is not inconsistent, it's just that `console.log` doesn't use `toString` method when logging an object. If you'd alerted that object, the result would be as you expected.

Comment: Has it ever been used at some point in time @Teemu?  `console.log`  using `toString()` ?

Comment: @Learnonhardway No (at least in standard `console` implementations - every environment can roll its own)

Answer (score 0):

That's the intended behaviour of `console.log()`. When you pass it an object, it prints out the object itself. It doesn't use `toString()` because that will prevent it from printing the object which is what it is intended to do. You can read more about its behaviour on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console).

If you want to force it to use `toString()`, then pass it `o.toString()` like this:

```js
var o = {
  valueOf: function () {
    return 1;
  },
  toString: function () {
    return 'haha, intercepted';
  }
};
console.log(o.toString());
```

Comment: No, I don't want to force it, I just thought it would work like `toValue` method as I explained above, which actually made me think about it.

Comment: It does work as expected when you pass the object to a function that expects a string like `alert()`. The `console.log` is the source of confusion here, not the `toString()`.